# SimpleJdbcCall works in windows but not linux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a spring boot application where I used SimpleJdbcCall to execute a stored procedure, everything works great in Windows (jdk1.8.0_111) but when I try to run it on a Linux server (using java 1.8.0_131) it throws the error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE banco.spcon_sesion; expected 18, got 0
```

This is my code:

```
@Override
public Usuario sesion(Credenciales credenciales) {

        SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withProcedureName("spcon_sesion")
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("in_usuario", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("in_contrasena", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("in_idSistema", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idUsuario", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombre", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_paterno", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_materno", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idPerfil", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombrePerfil", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idComercio", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombreComercio", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idTerminal", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombreTerminal", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idSucursal", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_referenciaRetiroEfectivo", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idProveedorSucursal", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_codigo", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_mensaje", Types.CHAR));

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("in_usuario", credenciales.getUsuario())
            .addValue("in_contrasena", credenciales.getContrasena())
            .addValue("in_idSistema", credenciales.getIdSistema());

        Map<String, Object> result = jdbcCall.execute(in);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Menu> menus = Menu
                .obtenerListaMenus((List<Map<String, Object>>) result.get("#result-set-1"));

        String codigo = (String) result.get("out_codigo");
        if (codigo != null && codigo.equals("00")) {
            try {

                return new Usuario(
                    Util.ifNullToLong(result.get("out_idUsuario"), 0L),
                    Util.ifNullToString(result.get("out_nombre"), ""),
                    Util.ifNullToString(result.get("out_paterno"), ""),
                    Util.ifNullToString(result.get("out_materno"), ""),
                    Util.ifNullToString(result.get("out_referenciaRetiroEfectivo"), ""),
                    Util.ifNullToLong(result.get("out_idComercio"), 0L),
                    Util.ifNullToString(result.get("out_nombreComercio"), ""),
                    Util.ifNullToLong(result.get("out_idTerminal"), 0L),
                    Util.ifNullToString(result.get("out_nombreTerminal"), ""),
                    Util.ifNullToLong(result.get("out_idPerfil"), 0L),
                    Util.ifNullToString(result.get("out_nombrePerfil"), ""),
                    Util.ifNullToLong(result.get("out_idSucursal"), 0L),
                    Util.ifNullToLong(result.get("out_idProveedorSucursal"), 0L),
                    menus
                );

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Also I try with a docker container with openjdk8 and the same error appear, can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please include the DDL for your stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I needed to add

```
.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
```

to the simpleJdbcCall like this:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withProcedureName("spcon_sesion")
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("in_usuario", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("in_contrasena", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("in_idSistema", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idUsuario", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombre", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_paterno", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_materno", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idPerfil", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombrePerfil", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idComercio", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombreComercio", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idTerminal", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_nombreTerminal", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idSucursal", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_referenciaRetiroEfectivo", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_idProveedorSucursal", Types.INTEGER))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_codigo", Types.CHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_mensaje", Types.CHAR));
```

Hope this help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're facing case-sensitivity issues (in some cases Win and MacOS ignore cases of identifiers). Check your settings, following [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

To start, try to remove all `declareParameters` - there's no need for them.

```
 SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                               .withProcedureName("spcon_sesion");

 SqlParameterSource in =
     new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("in_usuario", credenciales.getUsuario())
            .addValue("in_contrasena", credenciales.getContrasena())
            .addValue("in_idSistema", credenciales.getIdSistema());

 Map<String, Object> result = jdbcCall.execute(in);
```

If this not helps - instead of SpringBoot tools in this particular piece of code use pure [callable statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) to localize the problem. It would be also good to create a stored procedure with parameter names all in the same case (lower or upper) and test its call.

PS. I suppose there can be a problem in `jdbcTemplate` (if possible, provide its definition in the question), so to simplify the situation, consider using `new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)`.